# Google Cloud Storage file upload issue

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage, google-app-engine-python

I´m unable to upload files to GCS using the example on the link below:
https://cloud.google.com/python/getting-started/using-cloud-storage

It fails on the file `storage.py`, method: upload_file, exactly on the following call:

```
blob.upload_from_string(file_stream, content_type=content_type)
```

I've configured the ACL to myu bucket and enabled the required APIs as per the tutorial. I´ve also enabled billing.

I'm running the code on the local development server but using the GCS default bucket name configured on the project.

Python version 2.7

Comment: Can you show the traceback?

Comment: The development server does not really show an error or anything.... It just show http 500. Even running with the debug flags, the local development server is not so great for debugging I guess. I found that it fails on the blob.upload_from_string() by adding a couple of logging statements on the upload_file() method inside the storage.py file

Comment: Do you have debug enabled for your app? The traceback *might* only show if the flag is set.

Comment: I have the following on my main file:


if __name__ == "__main__":
 app.debug = True

Comment: Just enabled some more logging and found the following error message:

Caused by SSLError(\"Can\'t connect to HTTPS URL because the SSL module is not available.\",))

Comment: Where are you trying to run your code?

Comment: It's an external server, outside of Google cloud infrastructure.

Comment: Why do you have the tags for Google App Engine if this code is running outside Google?

Comment: Because I'm running the the development server outside of Google environment only. but the whole idea is to simply run gclould app deploy when ready to prod. It's just a development server with Google SDK installed.

Comment: Are you running this code in a webserver (WSGI or Gunicorn or ...)?

Comment: It's just the dev_appserver.py ...

Comment: You are leaving out details that can help figure out the problem.

Comment: I'm sure is related to Google app engine since the app engine runs inside the Google Clould infrastructure isn't it ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have taken a look at the Getting started tutorial, and for what I can see, it is built to be used in Python3 runtime.

You can check the `app.yaml` file, in the case of the tutorial [3-binary-data](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/getting-started-python/blob/master/3-binary-data/app.yaml) it is specifying the python3 runtime, and all the commands in the tutorial are thought to be used in Python3 as well (i.e. `virtualenv -p python3 env` builds an environment to be used with the python3 interpreter).

As well, the libraries used, for example `google.cloud.storage` are deprecated in Python  2.7 (you can check it [here](https://googleapis.github.io/google-cloud-python/latest/storage/index.html)), not that it means that it is unusable in Python2.7, only that it is not supported, and this might cause issues.

I would recommend you to use Python3 instead of Python2.7, and check if the issue persists.

Comment: I ran  it on a python3 environment and  it worked smoothly. Spot on mate !